# Flutter web getting blank white screen

Tags: flutter, dart

The web app was working fine, but when I added firebase to it, it started giving a blank screen with an error:

> Error: Assertion failed:
> file:///D:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.6/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:273:11

i am using master branch

Pubspec.yaml:

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.0-228.0.dev <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_svg:  # help us to use SVG in our app
  provider: # for State management
  firebase_auth:
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  firebase_core: ^1.18.0
  firebase_core_web: ^1.6.5
  cloud_firestore: ^3.2.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="ecomm">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>ecomm</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function(engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function(appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your firebase app properly in main file.

```
 main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: ********, 
    appId: ******, 
    messagingSenderId: **, projectId: *****);

}
```